# install aws cli on cloud9

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

Has anyone else encountered this error on cloud9 when trying to install the AWS cli. I followed the instructions [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/sample-aws-cli.html) as follows:

```
sudo yum -y update          # (1) Install the latest system updates.
sudo yum -y install aws-cli # (2) Install the AWS CLI.
aws --version               # (3) Confirm the AWS CLI was installed.
```

When I run (2) a message appears saying the install is complete. But when I run (3) the following error message appears:

```
$ aws --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/aws", line 19, in <module>
    import awscli.clidriver
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 36, in <module>
    from awscli.help import ProviderHelpCommand
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/awscli/help.py", line 20, in <module>
    from docutils.core import publish_string
  File "/home/ec2-user/environment/python_packages/docutils/core.py", line 246
    print('\n::: Runtime settings:', file=self._stderr)
                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Has anyone else encountered this error? Managed to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have most likely installed the wrong/outdated version of awscli.

It is [recommended](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-install.html#install-tool-pip) to install awscli via pip.

```
pip3 install awscli --upgrade --user
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, I've tried: "python3 -m pip install awscli --upgrade --user" and it appeared to install showing the message: "Installing collected packages: botocore, awscli
Successfully installed awscli-1.16.125 botocore-1.12.115" however when I run: "aws --version" I get the same error as above

Comment: Did you uninstall the yum awscli? It is probably still pointing to that one

Comment: I just tried: "sudo yum -y remove aws-cli" which said it removed it, then pip installed again and tried 'aws --version' and I get: "aws --version
bash: /usr/bin/aws: No such file or directory"

Comment: True running "/usr/local/bin/aws --version"
This is the location pip installs it in. The /usr/bin/aws one is still a reference to the wrong one

Comment: Thanks again, this seems to work -  for some unusual reason this isn't in the path, now I've added it and it works. For some reason my cloud9 instance doesn't have this path set by default which was a bit unexpected.

Comment: Great! Feel free to mark this answer as the solution so it will help others in the future.

Comment: To me, it is astounding that Cloud9 does not launch with the latest version installed.

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install awscli -upgrade –user

# Then set you path to point to the new version 

export PATH=~/.local/bin:$PATH

# awscli may need updated openSSL 

pip install pyOpenSSL --upgrade
```